# how to create .ipa from xcode using certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, code-signing, ipa

Right now I am working on a **phonegap-ios** application , now I have completed the app, client gave me certificate `.cer` , `.cerficatesigningreques`t ,`.p12` every cerficate that required in building `.ipa` file process.
I have now both  **distribution and development** included .cer,.p12 certificate ...

So can I create a .ipa file from XCode using client certificate?
 If YES the how ?
I have searched on google and SO but have not found any relevant answers.

or do I have to create certificate again from my PC using client account?

Using build.phonegap.com & client certificate  ,I can create .ipa but i used plugin and  some plugin do not work in that .ipa file.

Comment: Please refer:  
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi refer this link of test fight this may help  you it with screen shot 
refer this link http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-

before start this install profile in keychain by double click on it and same way you need to install .p12 in keychain.than start from 3 step from link hope this may help you.